# Sylius product and resource bundle together

Tags: symfony, sylius

I have installed ProductBundle and it works nice. What I mean "nice" a manager and a factory works as supposed. But then I wanted to use sylius routes and controllers with views. I had no guess if they come with product bundle or I need resource bundle. And I installed resource bundle. I added configuration to routes

```
app_product:
    resource: |
        alias: sylius.product
    type: sylius.resource
```

After that I had products routes in `debug:route`. I went to `/products` but it showed an error `Unable to find template "/index.html.twig" (looked into: D:\os526\domains\db\app/Resources/views`. Seems like the templates namespace is missed. And therefore I suppose configuration for routes should be different. But I cannot find how sylius do it by itself (its code is really huge). So, what is the proper configuration for routes and contollers?